# Error while starting start-all.sh (HADOOP)

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

Below is the error message i am getting while starting hadoop daemons using `start-all.sh`: [attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYcwP.png)

```
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r 91f2b7a13d1e97be65db92ddabc627cc29ac0009; compiled by 'jdu' on 2017-03-17T04:12Z
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.8.0_121
cat: /usr/local/hadoop/conf/slaves: No such file or directory
```

What are the fixes?

Comment: Is this path(/usr/local/hadoop/conf/slaves) for slave exists?. Recheck your hadoop directory path and update the same in conf

Comment: That is not a error, you can go and use hadoop, if all the services are running. use `jps` to check daemon state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the error message it seems that you are missing `slaves` file in `/usr/local/hadoop/conf/` directory. you can create one

If you are running `hadoop`  in `local/pseudo` mode then just put `localhost` in that file

If you are running `hadoop` in `cluster` mode then you need to add either `ip`s or `hostname`s of all the `slave-machines` in the cluster.

Comment: great to hear that @ShubhamJoshi. Accept  and upvote shall help me too. :)